# Output is not showing after searching for an element from the database, howsoever the database connection has been established

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

Here is the UI of search box :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="searchme">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:orange; color:white;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
</form>
        </div>
```

Here is part of my card having the search db connection:

```
String query=request.getParameter("searchme");
String data;
if (query!=null){
    data="select * from  order_details where Customer_name like '%"+query+"%' or order_Date like '%"+query+"%' or approved_By like '%"+query+"%' or order_ID like '%"+query+"%' or Customer_ID like '%"+query+"%' or  order_Amount like '%"+query+"%' or notes like '%"+query+"%' or approval_Status like ' % " +query+ " % ' ";    
        
}
else{
    
    data= "select * from order_details by Customer_ID";
}
```

the code isn't giving any output, it is part of a bigger code where the database connection works fine. Please show me why can't I get search results.

Comment: Are you seeing any error  ? Try printing `query` value and see if thats showing right value . Also , for db code try with custom data and see if that shows right value

Comment: yeah it is showing the write value, but database is not fetching the output results.

Comment: Where is your code to fetch datas ?

Comment: it's written in the question, please check

Comment: I am seeing only query code no fetch codes .

Comment: You don't show how you execute your query. Also, your current solution is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not concatenate values into a query string, but use a prepared statement with parameters.